# Project contains at least one plugin that requires a system library. This is not supported with ANT. Please build using gradle

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, gradle, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

Im build cordova app at **VS 2013 CTP3.2 with Apache Cordova version 5.2.0**.
Everthing working good until add this plugin :

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

When try to build get this message:

**Project contains at least one plugin that requires a system library. This is not supported with ANT. Please build using gradle.**

[image]

I have already gradle installed version 2.6

[image]

Can anyone help me to figured this out and solve this problem...

I Have whole android sdk stuff installed :
[image]

Comment: try installing plugin by running this `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-push-notification` .

Comment: i added trough visual studio wizard

Comment: that not solved my problem

Comment: the problem is about compiling the project

Comment: STILL HAVING THE PROBLEM!
NOBODY CAN HELP PLS?

Comment: can you share me the command which is being used by you to build the same?

Answer (score 0):

To use gradle add 
    
to your config.xml before the plugins declaration